# Can you remove the garage door sensors?

Tags: garage-door

I have tried everything to adjust and fix the sensors on my garage door. They will not close when the sun is hitting them. Can I just remove them?

Comment: See [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/723/how-do-i-compensate-for-the-sun-confusing-my-garage-door-openers-sensors) question

Answer (score 9):

The sensors are a safety requirement. Excess sunlight may be saturating them to the point they cannot pickup the signal from the other one. I would suggest adding some kind of shade or hood around which one is picking up light from the other. An empty toilet paper cardboard roll might work, depending on how the sensor is placed around the door track.